# How to calculate percentage value in XAML

Tags: wpf

I have Circle `Progress-Bar` and simple label inside this `Circle`

```
<DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar x:Name="CircularProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
     Percentage="0"  />

<Label Name="lblProgress" Content="0%" Foreground="White"  Grid.Column="1" />
```

I have 2 static field:

1. In my `main form class` - totalFiles
2. As a `class member`:

   public class Data
   {
       public static int numberOfFiles;
   }

So in this `Circle` and my `label` i want to show my percentage by calculate: `(Data.numberOfFiles\totalFiles) * 100`

So how can i do that via `XAML` ?

**Edit**

Add new class that hold my form variable:

```
public class TotalPacketInList
{
    private static int _value;

    public static int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

My `DoubleToPercentageConverter` class:

```
public class DoubleToPercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("{0%}", (int)(((double)Data.numberOfFiles/ TotalFilesInList.Value) * 100));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

<Label Name="lblCircleProgress" Content="{Binding ElementName=CircularProgressBar,Path=Percentage, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToPercentage}}"
       Grid.Column="1" />
```

this will calculate my percentage but when i try to run my application i have exception in my `label`:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

> Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '481' and line position '45'.

This is because when the application start the value `TotalPacketInList.Value` is zero and my calculation is divided by zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Converters. In order to create a converter:

1. Create a folder named "converter" and add a new class inside it i.e: `DoubleToPercentageConverter.cs`
2. this class must implement the interface IValueConverter.

   ```
   public class DoubleToPercentageConverter: IValueConverter
   {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
        //Don't know if the Double cast is neccessary
        return string.Format("{0%}", ((Double)value).ToString()));
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
   }
   ```
3. add your logic inside the `Convert` method and return a value.. for example:

   `return value.ToString() + "%";`
4. Inside xaml add this in you resources

   `<converter:DoubleToPercentageConverter x:Key="DoubleToPercentage"/>`

   where converter is the folder in which you created the converter
5. Bind the converter to the element:

   `<Label Name="lblProgress" Content="{Binding ElementName=CircularProgressBar,Path=Percentage, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToPercentage}}" Foreground="White"  Grid.Column="1" />`
6. In your  `Timer_Tick` event set the `Percentage` value of the progress bar to your calculeted value:

   ```
   CircularProgressBar.Percentage = (int)(((double)Data.numberOfFiles/ TotalFilesInList.Value) * 100))
   ```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: i need this 2 methods in the class example in section 2 ? or only implement my own method like you wrote

Comment: When you make your class implement `IValueConverter` you will be obliged to add these two methods. This is because `IValueConverter` is an `Interface` and you must implement all the methods inside that interface! To simplify the process, after typing ` :IValueConverter` hover your mouse on it and visual studio will suggest you to implement the missing methods! ;) You can leave `ConverBack` empty.

Comment: OK i implemented this class and after add to windows.resources i have compilation error: Error 4 The type 'converter:DoubleToPercentageConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

Comment: I have this in my XAML: xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyApp.classes" but the folder converter is not inside the folder classes, should i put in inside ?

Comment: add `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.converter" ` if you converter folder is in the root folder

Comment: Finally i put in in my classes folder but now i have another issue after try your code, please see my update

Comment: in your convert method before the return instruction add if(TotalPacketInList.Value==0) return "0%";

Comment: also, notice that the convert method will be called every time the Percentage property of the CircularProgressBar changes. You can get this value inside the converter by using the value parameter, and for what I can see, you're not using this value. So you probably need to add in codeBehind some code that change the Percentage value of your CircularProgressBar, or add another converter for the CircularProgressBar if you want to do all in xaml

Comment: the value that the convert return will be the same for the CircularProgressBar (but without the '%') - how can i update my CircularProgressBar  also via XAML ?

Comment: I need to know more about your application to answer this question.. for example... where you assign the `Value` in TotalPacketInList?
Is a user control the xaml that contains the circle probress bar and the label? Is the Percentage a value that change like you are actually downloading a file, or is value that will be assigned once while the page is loading? Post more details please

Comment: i have ObservableCollection collection that hold all my objects inside and  this objects properties  changing and then my totalFiles also changing and i am calculate my percentage so i created timer and in this timer i am checking my properties and changes my CircularProgressBar and then convert method will is called.  but i want to know if i can do that without the timer

Comment: So, first set the Percentage value of your CircleProgressBar inside the Timer_Tick event.. Then change the convert method as indicated in my post (I will update it right away).  and let me know if it works!

Then, to answer to tour question: _if I can do that without the timer_ I don't think you can do all this thing in XAML.. Keep the timer solution, is not bad imho, or trigger some event to avoid Timer.. Is there any event you can use to being notified when your data changes? In which circumstance your data will change?

Comment: My data changing every few seconds, why i cannot use in my CircularProgressbar percentage field the same value like in my label content property ? the both need the same value ! (between 0 and 100)

Comment: Of course you can use a converter also in your CircleProgressBar, you have to change some thing, for example you have to return a Double instead of a String. Then I want to explain this piece of code: `Content="{Binding ElementName=CircularProgressBar,Path=Percentage, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToPercentage}}"`. So what are you doing here? Well, you take the value of the element named CircularProgressBar, in particular, the property Percentage, and pass that value to a converter named DoubleToPercentage that return another value based on Percentage.  [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] To do the same whit the circularProgressBar where are you taking the value? You can set the value from a Timer for example... Or.. I don't know.. you have to set the value somewhere.. you can't do all the stuff in xaml.. If is not a problem can you upload your project? (github etc) maybe we can figure out how to do what you want..